# Node.js / Delete content in file

Tags: node.js

I want to delete the content of a simple text file with node.js.
Or replace the file with a new/empty one.

How can I achieve this in node?

Comment: Have you looked here? http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: downvoted for lack of research

Comment: Isn't this the default behavior of fs.writeFile, if you don't supply flags???  It's actually harder to append to append to a file...

Comment: @PeterLyons: I had a look at the docs but there are a lot of methods lacking explanation.

Comment: @ectomorph:  From the docs about fs.writeFile: Asynchronously writes data to a file, replacing the file if it already exists.  Seems pretty straight forward to me.  I miss the days when you could throw in links to LMGTFY...   http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback

Comment: @ectomorph a lot of the stuff in the fs module is just wrappers around  system calls, so you will have a pretty good hit rate if you look for more documentation in your system's man pages. `man truncate` is a good example example.

Comment: @ChrisCM: I was looking for replacing content first - so I have not seen this. Sorry - next time I will be more accurate. But posting questions on SO usually gives you some additional info. E.g. today I learned what LMGTFY means. Big thanks for that ...

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You are looking for [`fs.truncate`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_truncate_path_len_callback) or [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

Either of the following will work:

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.truncate('/path/to/file', 0, function(){console.log('done')})
```

or

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.writeFile('/path/to/file', '', function(){console.log('done')})
```

There are also [synchronous versions](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_truncatesync_path_len) of [both functions](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) that can be useful in some scenarios.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why synchronous versions are undesirable?

Comment: Sure! The main reason is that node is single threaded (for the most part), so if you do expensive synchronous operations, you block execution for your whole process.

Comment: not sure why but neither of these seem to zero out the file for me.

Comment: As of 10-Feb-2020 the first example in this answer can be shortened to `const fs = require('fs');` and then `fs.truncate(filePath, () => { });`. Since it is now available I'd also recommend using `const` instead of `var` to avoid unwanted side effects in particular if you're working with a larger code base.

Comment: There are valid (unique) reasons to prefer `truncate` or `truncateSync`, and `writeFile` or `writeFileSync`.  I disagree with the idea that they should not be used.  The right tool should be used depending on the circumstances.

Comment: @blong yeah I agree that there's a place for both (a decade late) :) I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

[fs.unlink](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_fs_unlink_path_callback) is the call you need to delete a file. To replace it with different contents, just overwrite it with `fs.writeFile`.

Comment: From node documentation for fs.writeFile: Asynchronously writes data to a file, replacing the file if it already exists. Your unlink step is unnecessary.

Comment: @ChrisCM I'm just answering both parts of the question.