# Clear the content of text file in node.js

Tags: node.js

This is my code for JScript file

```
fs.open("SensorDataValue.txt",'a' , function(err, fd) { 
if(err) {
    throw 'error opening file: ' + err;
}
fs.write(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(err) {
if (err) throw 'error writing file: ' + err;
fs.close(fd, function() {
console.log("V 14 The file was saved!" + "\r\n");
});
```

This will keep appending any text to the 'SensorDataValue" text file.

However, what I want to achieve is :

To clear the content of text file before it appends. So every time, I use the script file, it will always clear the text file **FIRST** before appending any data in it.

How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: Please go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371224/node-js-delete-content-in-file). This tackle similar type of scenerio.

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = 'Hello World!!'
var fs = require('fs');

fs.unlink(__dirname + '/proto.js', (err) => {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    writeData(data)
})


function writeData(data) {

    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/proto.js', data, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, data);
        } else {

            console.log('Data uploaded')
        }


    })


}
```

Comment: While deleting a file and recreating it is one thing, what stops him from using fs#writeFile with `''` to clear it, then fs#appendFile to write data? Less of a transaction.

Comment: @Crowes or just use `fs.writeFile()` with the flag `w`, I don't understand why the data should be appended if the goal is to re-write the file each time.

Comment: @robertklep That is the default flag, which is why I didn't mention it. :P He could even use fs#writeFile again and declare flag `a` instead of using fs#appendFile.

Comment: @Crowes sorry, what I meant was: why not use `fs.writeFile` to directly write the data, instead of first writing an empty string and then appending the data? Using `w` the existing data will be overwritten anyway.

Comment: @robertklep If he hardcoded the flag or didn't declare one, it would just overwrite each time, it would never append (afaik)

Comment: @Crowes perhaps I don't understand the question, but it seems like they're asking that every time, the file is first cleared and then the data is appended (as if they don't know what the `a` flag does).

Comment: better than deleting and re-creating the file; is clearing its content using
`fs.truncate('/path/to/file', 0, function(){console.log('done')})`